# Group Comma Delimited String into Range Groups 2 Dimentional Array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, sql-server, multidimensional-array

I have a comma delimited string that I need to break into array ranges that can be passed into SQL server's BETWEEN statement.

For instance, say I have the following string below, I need the corresponding returnVal returned;

```
string delimited = "1,2,5,6,7,8,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19"; 
returnVal = int[,] ranges = new int[4, 2] { { 1, 2 }, { 5, 8 }, { 11, 13 }, { 15, 19 } };
```

My SQL Between Statement would then look like

```
WHERE (ID BETWEEN 1 AND 2) OR (ID BETWEEN 5 AND 8)  OR (ID BETWEEN 11 AND 13)  OR (ID BETWEEN 15 AND 19)
```

Rather than

WHERE ID IN(1,2,5,6,7,8,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19)

My actual delimited string is over 5000 IDs so I need to use BETWEEN statements rather than IN statements for efficiency.

What would be the most efficient way to do this using C#?

Comment: What is the logic for the ranges? there are 14 number but you only use 8

Comment: I saw the question and dont see anything suggesting the logic behind

Comment: You are probably asking the wrong question [**What is the XY problem?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) If you have 5000 id create a temporal table with index and do a join.

Comment: A given ID value cannot be "between 1 and 2" **AND** "between 5 and 8". So your <would look like> version is logically incorrect. If you desire to use ranges, you need to use OR, not AND. Agree with Juan - Erland discusses the use of a TVP [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html)

Comment: Good point, I have modified my question according to your comment.

Comment: Join solution won't work, I need to send the IDs over a HTTP GET REQUEST and am limited to how much data I can send, I need to send over ranges rather than individuals IDs. I've posted solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will solve your problem:

If your ints are a delimited string you can use split to convert it into an int array.

```
var intArray = **array of integers**
var ranges = new List<List<int>>();

int? topRange = intArray[0];
int? lastId = null;
int bottomRange; 
foreach(int id in intArray)
{
    if(topRange == null)
    {
        topRange = id;
    }
    if (lastId != null && id != (lastId + 1))
    {
        bottomRange = lastId.Value;
        ranges.Add(new List<int>() { topRange.Value, bottomRange });
        topRange = id;
    }
    lastId = id;
}
```